# How can I stop my scrollbar "bouncing" into and out of existence

Tags: spacemacs, osx, scroll-bars

I just installed Spacemacs on a new Mac and am getting some weird behavior—the scroll bar appears when I scroll (making the window wider), then disappears when I stop scrolling. This doesn't happen on my other MacBook so I'm not sure exactly what's going on.

[image: a scroll bar popping into and out of existence]

Basic things I've tried to see where the issue might be:

- This happens on the emacs included in brew-cask and on emacs-plus, so it's not build-specific
- This doesn't happen if I move `~/.emacs.d` so I'm just on a vanilla emacs install. With scroll bars enabled, they stay, with them disabled, they stay gone. So something in the Spacemacs config is triggering this.

Wondering if anybody has a clue what the issue is here.

Comment: check the the scroll command you used, see if any advice attached? or anything in window-scroll-functions?

Answer (score 4):

I searched for `scroll` in the Spacemacs source and found that this is a recently added feature:

```lisp
(spacemacs|defc dotspacemacs-scroll-bar-while-scrolling t
  "Show the scroll bar while scrolling. The auto hide time can be configured by
setting this variable to a number."
  '(choice boolean number)
  'spacemacs-dotspacemacs-init)
```

You can disable it in your `dotspacemacs/init`:

```lisp
dotspacemacs-scroll-bar-while-scrolling nil
```

Answer (score 0):

Find this code (it is inside `(defun dotspacemacs/init ()` part of your `.spacemacs` config file:

```
   ;; Show the scroll bar while scrolling. The auto hide time can be configured
   ;; by setting this variable to a number. (default t)
   dotspacemacs-scroll-bar-while-scrolling t
```

and change it to:

```
   ;; Show the scroll bar while scrolling. The auto hide time can be configured
   ;; by setting this variable to a number. (default t)
   dotspacemacs-scroll-bar-while-scrolling nil
```

Then restart Emacs and the scrollbars should be gone.